# Infinite loop while compiling template

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Why does this course compiler to go to infinite loop. I'm using visual studio 2012 (Compiler VC++11).

```
template <unsigned N, unsigned To = N - 1>
struct is_prime
{
    static const bool value = (N % To != 0) && is_prime<N, To - 1>::value;
};

template <unsigned N>
struct is_prime<N, 1>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <unsigned N>
struct is_prime<N, 0>
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <unsigned N>
struct next_prime
{
private:
    static const unsigned n_plus_one = N + 1;
public:
    static const unsigned value = is_prime<n_plus_one>::value ? n_plus_one : next_prime<n_plus_one>::value;
};

int main()
{
    cout << is_prime<5>::value << endl;   //Compiles. true.
    cout << is_prime<4>::value << endl;   //Compiles. false.
    cout << next_prime<4>::value << endl; //Infinite compiler loop.
    return 0;
}
```

And if I'll write the specialization of `next_prime<100>` without member `value`:

```
template <>
struct next_prime<100>
{

};
```

I'll see the compiler error. So, why is it even trying to compile it?

Comment: btw, starting at sqrt(N) instead of N-1 will be a massive speedup.  To permit much larger N, have a `is_divisible_by<N, Min, Max>` predicate that divides the range and recurses, giving you log recursion depth instead of linear.  Fancier would be to generate a sieve -- each 'returns' a list of primes, and is passed to the next interval.  Just, you know, stuff to work on.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it evaluates `next_prime<4>::value`:

```
template <unsigned N>
struct next_prime {
// ...
static const unsigned n_plus_one = N + 1;
// ...
static const unsigned value = is_prime<n_plus_one>::value ? n_plus_one : next_prime<n_plus_one>::value;
```

In the above `next_prime<n_plus_one>::value` must only be instantiated when `is_prime<n_plus_one>::value` is `false`.

You can fix it with `std::conditional<>` which returns one of the types, depending on the condition:

```
template <unsigned N>
struct next_prime : std::conditional<
      is_prime<N + 1>::value
    , std::integral_constant<unsigned, N + 1> // not instantiated here
    , next_prime<N + 1>                       // not instantiated here
    >::type                                   // instantiated here
{};
```

Comment: `next_prime<4>::value` calls `is_prime<5>::value` it is `true` so the answers should be `5` as I understand.

Comment: `?:` doesn't "evaluate" both branches in the usual sense (as in, `foo ? launch_satellite() : fire_missile();` will only do one of those two things), but it does cause instantiation of `next_prime<n_plus_one>`, and so on, causing infinite recursion.

Comment: So `?:` operator has a difference in working in compile-time and run-time. Interesting...